# Center Checkbox on its label in a Table in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, view

In my Project I am working on a few index views that only have a few fields.  When their are few fields in a table the label and the checkbox below them never line up.  As one example, in the code below the Active field is a checkbox and it is not under its label.  How can I get it so the checkbox is centered on its label?

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BranchName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Active)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(m => m.Active).ThenBy(m => m.BranchName))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BranchName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBranch", new { id=item.BranchId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Here is a pic to see how ugly it looks:

[image]

Comment: this doesn't appear to be the default behavior as far as i can tell.   default should left align the checkbox with the header

Comment: @JamieD77 look at the picture that I posted below.  Maybe there is a css change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add css to the column, via colspan or direct on td or th

```
<td style="text-align: center">
```

OR

```
style="float:left"
```

Otherwise encapsulate the @Html.DisplayFor in a div with that style.

Finally don't have the css inline and move to the style.css file.